# phpvirtualbox error at login prompt

Tags: virtualbox

Groovy Gorilla

[image]

When I change from myipadrress to 127.0.0.1 and vice-versa I get the login and enter admin/admin but get the error below. The vboxwebserver is up and the config.php is modified accordingly.  What is wrong?

> Oracle VM VirtualBox VM Selector v6.1.16_Ubuntu
>
> PhpVirtualBox 5.0-5   2016-01-08

etc/default/virtualbox:

```
LOAD_VBOXDRV_MODULE=1

VBOXWEB_USER=brad
VBOXWEB_GROUP=vboxusers
VBOXWEB_HOST=127.0.0.1
```

PHP 7.4.9 (cli) (built: Oct 26 2020 15:17:14) ( NTS )

libapache2-mod-php7.4 is already the newest version (7.4.9-1ubuntu1.1).

vboxwebsrv is running and is listening:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:18083         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          727122     11337/vboxwebsrv
```

There was an error obtaining the list of registered virtual machines from VirtualBox. Make sure vboxwebsrv is running and that the settings in config.php are correct.
The list of virtual machines will not begin auto-refreshing again until this page is reloaded.

```
HTTP error: 500 Internal Server Error
Details

readyState: "4"
responseText: ""
status: "500"
statusText: "Internal Server Error"
```

the log file:

```
00:00:00.039894 main     VirtualBox web service 6.1.16_Ubuntu r140961 linux.amd64 (Dec 17 2020 22:06:23) release log
00:00:00.039905 main     Log opened 2021-02-19T01:02:40.234693000Z
00:00:00.039907 main     Build Type: release
00:00:00.039913 main     OS Product: Linux
00:00:00.039916 main     OS Release: 5.8.0-31-generic
00:00:00.039918 main     OS Version: #33-Ubuntu SMP Mon Nov 23 18:44:54 UTC 2020
00:00:00.039990 main     DMI Product Name: HP 15 Notebook PC
00:00:00.040015 main     DMI Product Version: 0974100002405F00000620180
00:00:00.040038 main     Firmware type: BIOS
00:00:00.040172 main     Host RAM: 3826MB (3.7GB) total, 1375MB available
00:00:00.040178 main     Executable: /usr/lib/virtualbox/vboxwebsrv
00:00:00.040179 main     Process ID: 8869
00:00:00.040180 main     Package type: LINUX_64BITS_GENERIC (OSE)
00:00:00.241060 main     IPC socket path: /tmp/.vbox-root-ipc/ipcd
00:00:01.548109 SQPmp    Socket connection successful: host = 127.0.0.1, port = 18083, master socket = 9
00:00:06.515677 Watchdog Statistics: 0 websessions, 0 references
00:01:41.836230 SQPmp    Request 1 on socket 10 queued for processing (1 items on Q)
00:01:41.836325 SQW01    New SOAP thread started
00:01:41.836389 SQPmp    Request 2 on socket 11 queued for processing (2 items on Q)
00:01:41.836429 SQW01    Processing connection from IP=127.0.0.1 socket=10 (0 out of 1 threads idle)
00:01:41.836902 SQPmp    Request 3 on socket 12 queued for processing (2 items on Q)
00:09:25.294865 SQW03    Processing connection from IP=127.0.0.1 socket=10 (5 out of 6 threads idle)



netstat -plant|g 18083
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:18083         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      10481/vboxwebsrv    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:37690         127.0.0.1:18083         ESTABLISHED 5649/apache2        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:18083         127.0.0.1:37690         ESTABLISHED 10481/vboxwebsrv    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:18083         127.0.0.1:37678         ESTABLISHED 10481/vboxwebsrv    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:37688         127.0.0.1:18083         ESTABLISHED 10960/apache2       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:18083         127.0.0.1:37680         ESTABLISHED 10481/vboxwebsrv    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:18083         127.0.0.1:37686         ESTABLISHED 10481/vboxwebsrv    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:37680         127.0.0.1:18083         ESTABLISHED 3224/apache2        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:37686         127.0.0.1:18083         ESTABLISHED 8957/apache2        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:18083         127.0.0.1:37688         ESTABLISHED 10481/vboxwebsrv    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:18083         127.0.0.1:37682         ESTABLISHED 10481/vboxwebsrv    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:37682         127.0.0.1:18083         ESTABLISHED 10042/apache2       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:37678         127.0.0.1:18083         ESTABLISHED 9761/apache2
```

and then:

```
netstat -plant|g 18083
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:18083         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      10481/vboxwebsrv    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:37708         127.0.0.1:18083         TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:37718         127.0.0.1:18083         TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:37720         127.0.0.1:18083         TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:37704         127.0.0.1:18083         TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:37722         127.0.0.1:18083         TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:37710         127.0.0.1:18083         TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:37724         127.0.0.1:18083         TIME_WAIT   -
```

Uninstalled VB 6.1.16 and downloaded/installed VB 6.1.18.

> Oracle VM VirtualBox VM Selector v6.1.18

and the vboxwebsrv.log is something like:

```
00:00:00.176230 main     VirtualBox web service 6.1.18 r142142 linux.amd64 (Jan  7 2021 17:36:17) release log
00:00:00.176236 main     Log opened 2021-02-28T15:32:53.971575000Z
00:00:00.176237 main     Build Type: release
00:00:00.176242 main     OS Product: Linux
00:00:00.176245 main     OS Release: 5.8.0-31-generic
00:00:00.176248 main     OS Version: #33-Ubuntu SMP Mon Nov 23 18:44:54 UTC 2020
00:00:00.176301 main     DMI Product Name: HP 15 Notebook PC
00:00:00.176327 main     DMI Product Version: 0974100002405F00000620180
00:00:00.176348 main     Firmware type: BIOS
00:00:00.176456 main     Host RAM: 3826MB (3.7GB) total, 1528MB available
00:00:00.176461 main     Executable: /usr/lib/virtualbox/vboxwebsrv
00:00:00.176462 main     Process ID: 14689
00:00:00.176463 main     Package type: LINUX_64BITS_UBUNTU_19_10
00:00:00.226365 main     IPC socket path: /tmp/.vbox-brad-ipc/ipcd
00:00:03.740572 SQPmp    Socket connection successful: host = 127.0.0.1, port = 18083, master socket = 9
00:00:08.662529 Watchdog Statistics: 0 websessions, 0 references
00:03:17.758674 SQPmp    Request 1 on socket 10 queued for processing (1 items on Q)
00:03:17.758755 SQW01    New SOAP thread started
00:03:17.758904 SQW01    Processing connection from IP=127.0.0.1 socket=10 (0 out of 1 threads idle)
00:03:18.198560 SQW01    External authentication library is 'VBoxAuth'
00:03:18.728039 SQPmp    Request 2 on socket 14 queued for processing (1 items on Q)
00:03:18.728124 SQW02    New SOAP thread started
00:03:18.728244 SQW02    Processing connection from IP=127.0.0.1 socket=14 (0 out of 2 threads idle)
00:03:18.931960 SQW01    Access for user 'brad' granted
00:03:19.032412 SQW02    Access for user 'brad' granted
00:03:19.088837 SQPmp    Request 3 on socket 12 queued for processing (1 items on Q)
00:03:19.088946 SQW03    New SOAP thread started
00:03:19.089123 SQW03    Processing connection from IP=127.0.0.1 socket=12 (0 out of 3 threads idle)
00:03:19.195974 SQW03    Access for user 'brad' granted
00:03:19.409464 SQPmp    Request 4 on socket 13 queued for processing (1 items on Q)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the newer versions of Ubuntu will often default to IPv6 rather than IPv4 for internal lookups. If PhpVirtualBox is not running on a publicly-accessible machine, you might want to change your `VBOXWEB_HOST` to use `0.0.0.0` instead. This will ensure the tool responds to all requests.

If you have PhpVirtualBox launch at startup via `systemd`, then you'll also need to update the `/etc/systemd/service/vboxweb.service` (the file name may be different on your machine) file like so:

```
[Service]
Environment=VBOXWEB_HOST=0.0.0.0
```

Then restart the VirtualBox web service with:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart vboxweb
```

Comment: vboxweb is starting the vboxwebsrv and listen p 18083 on IPv4. I will try that.

Comment: Nothing. Also VBOXWEB_HOST and any other settings in /etc/default/virtualbox are wasted... It is not read. Maybe here is an issue. I gibberish it and no errors ...

Comment: also, I have not found why the login prompt randomly disappeared.